# Total hamiltonian is time independent in interaction picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

There is this general statement in [Ashok](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812832866) which, if it's true, could someone explain why it is true?

Regarding the interaction picture:

> Since $H_0$ is time independent in the interaction picture (see (6.51)), 
>       it follows that the total Hamiltonian is time independent in the 
>       interaction picture.

I don't think this is right, but I can be wrong. The point is that in the Schrödinger picture

$$
H^{(S)} = H_0^{(S)} + H_I^{(S)}, 
$$

and then, in the interaction picture

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H^{(IP)} &= e^{iH_0^{(IP)}t}(H_0^{(S)} + H_I^{(S)})e^{-iH_0^{(IP)}t} \\
&= H_0^{(IP)} +  e^{iH_0^{(IP)}t}H_I^{(S)}e^{-iH_0^{(IP)}t}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Obviously, $H_0$ is time independent but in general, the interaction part $H_I$ is not, so I don't see why $H$ should be time-indepdendent as claimed.